# TableViewCell's textLabel value returns to 1 when cell is scrolled out of the view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, ipod

i have a table view in which i can add 1 or subtract 1 to the value of my `cell.textLabel.text` but when i switch views and return or scroll a cell out of the view, and when it comes back into view, the `textLabel`'s value returns to `1` which is the original starting point! Please help! Here is the code to add and subtract 1:

```
 - (IBAction)addLabelText:(id)sender{

    cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview]; // <-- ADD THIS LINE

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text  
                                                                intValue] +1];

}


- (IBAction)subtractLabelText:(id)sender
{
   cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];        
    if ( [[cell.textLabel text] intValue] == 0){ 
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text intValue] +0];
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text intValue] -1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are allocating a new cell each time.. and not using the cell re-usablility method.
In your case, when you are performing arithmetic actions to your previous values and you don't have an array to store previous values. The easiest way to fix this is make your Cell-Identifier unique. (something like @"Cell-%d",indexPAth.row)

Note: However, more efficient way would be to save your result in the array you are populating your data from, without making you Cell-Identifier unique.

Comment: okay, i took your advice and i added this: `- (IBAction)addLabelText:(id)sender{
    
    
    cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview]; 
  
       num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text  
                                                                intValue] +1];
    [number addObject:num];
    [myTableView reloadData];
    
}`
could this work? It adds fine, but i cannot get it to subtract and work! Thanks for the help +1

Comment: No! Your initial code (i.e, the code in your question) would work.
Supposing u've made the Cell identifier unique, Just add [myTableView reloadData] at the end of both methods.
And it should work. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because, the cells will be re-used on scrolling. The table view's datasource method will be invoked, hence the values get reset to the original value. You can maintain an array of `NSNumber`s as a datasource to the tableview (is, in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`: , set the text fo the cell label from the array). Each time you need to add or subtract, do it the corresponding `NSNumber` obj and re-load the tableview.

Comment: okay i think i understand what you are saying. I think i do the same with my tableView images. I have this code in my `cellForRow` method: `cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` is this what you are talking about? And i just have to change this to a NSNumber? Thanks a bunch for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating your data modal. That is why it is taking the original content value.

Comment: First, thank you for the help, secondly im not too sure what a modal is, so could you explain this a little more? THanks again

Answer (score 0):

After change the cell text value reload the tableview `[self.tableview reloadData]`